# How to change date with Shortcut App - iOS

Tags: iphone

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question but i will do it anyways.

I want to make a Iphone shortcut which adds to the current date one month.

For example:

Date before activating shortcut: 1 (Day).1 (Month).2023 (Year)

Date after activating shortcut: 1.2.2023

There is the block "Adjust date" but it does not add one month to the current date when i run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a month with the *adjust date* command.

For example: i added 1 month to todays date. 25/05/2023 becomes 25/06/23

The question is what do you want to do with the changed date?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is not possible. If you are trying to change the device Date&Time setting using shortcuts, it currently does not have this option.

The Adjust Date command is associated to the Calendar app. That is why it is a bit misleading. It is used to manipulate date variables so that you can use on other places, but you are not able to change the Date&Time in the Settings app.